# How do you breed better horses?

Tags: pocket-stables

I read that you could merge the traits when breeding but I do not know how.

Any general tips for breeding better horses ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you're looking for when breeding is their traits, and each horse can have a maximum of five traits.  Each breed of horse has two genetics it will pass on to their colts.

Traits are added in this manner:

- Your horse's traits, in the same order.
- The mare's traits, also in the same order.
- In the event that there are more than four traits, remove the first one provided by your horse.

Your first bred generation will not hit the trait limit, as it will gain all four traits from the mare's breed and your horse.  The second generation and on is where it gets interesting; the colt will gain four traits from the first generation, and two from the mare.

The trick to this is to choose a mare who's very first trait matches the last trait provided by your horse.  When this happens, the first one isn't knocked out as usual, but the mare's first trait combines with the last provided by your horse, making an improved version.

Combinations give a straight doubling of their stat limit.  They're essentially the same trait twice (and in fact, function the same, but only taking up one trait slot, instead of two).

eg:
Breeding a Northerner and a Seeker gives the first generation colt four traits:

```
Strength / Temper / Dexterity / Smarts
```

Breeding this horse with a Noblesse or Pinetree breed will result in a colt with:

```
Strength / Temper / Dexterity / Smarts+ / 
Dexterity from Noblesse or Strength from Pinetree
```

Breeding the first generation with a horse that doesn't have Smarts as the first trait will result in:

```
Temper / Dexterity / Smarts / <mare's two traits>
```

Combining this second generation (using the Pinetree example) horse with the Northener breed again will give:

```
Temper / Dexterity / Smarts+ / Strength+ / Temper
```

---

Traits only combine with the last/first combination.  Like the Pinetree combination shows, the horse can have the same trait more than once, and it will gain the benefits from both (ie. Strength gives +20 Vitality, two Strength traits give +40 Vitality).

I do not believe traits combine more than once (ie. Strength+ won't combine with Strength, or another Strength+), because the last trait is unimproved for every breed, except for Carrotop, and that requires something like a dozen pedigree papers to even consider using.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to edit my answer to put my findings, but your reply is already very complete. I am struggling at the moment to beat the second G1 race

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if two identical symbols appear contiguously in the new horse traits, they will merge in a stronger traits.

One should choose carefully which breeds they unlock in order to maximise the potential for strong traits.